# How to use JQuery.ajax to get the thumbnail attachment from each WordPress post?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

I'm trying to get a JSON response showing thumbnail attachments for each WordPress post.

I tried using the JQuery json-api plugin, but it gives me all attachments. I just want the thumbnail.

For example, I would like to use JQuery.ajax to get the thumbnail attachment urls from each WordPress post in JSON format, like this:

```
[{image_1: "thumbnail_image_a.jpg",
image_2: "thumbnail_image_b.jpg",
image_3: "thumbnail_image_c.jpg",
... etc}]
```

Should I write my own plugin? Or add something to functions.php? Or what is the least complex way?

Comment: Be more useful for you to post a little markup, just a suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should take a look at https://solislab.com/blog/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/ ( old site is down : http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/#admin-ajax ).

By adding a simple function with the right hooks in your **functions.php** you could end up with a nice way of getting exactly what you want.

Adapted from the url mentioned above:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myajax-submit', 'myajax_submit' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myajax-submit', 'myajax_submit' );

function myajax_submit() {
// get the submitted parameters
   $postID = $_POST['postID'];

   $response = get_thumbnail_images(); 
   $response = json_encode($response);

// response output
   header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
   echo $response;

// IMPORTANT: don't forget to "exit"
exit;
}
```

I call get_thumnail_images() where I might have a WP_Query or a SQL statement to get the information you need into an array.

Let's recap the wordpress part:
1) hooks

2) function that get's called based on the action parameter requested by the AjaxRequest (see url for full tutorial)

3) a logic function that will give us the thumbnails

4) the result is a json enconded array. You can do whatever you want with it on the front end.

Comment: Looks like that post has been taken down. Any other reference?

Comment: The post has been moved to this site: https://solislab.com/blog/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Updated post now.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use $.ajax to download the page via it's URL argument, then you would have to sort through the markup to find each post and get the thumbnail from it. I don't know the markup for a wordpress site, so I can't help you there.

It may work something like this:

```
 $.ajax('url.php',{
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            $.find('wordpress_comment_element').each(function(){
                var thumb=$(this).children('img').attr('src');
                //add thumb to JSON object
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. I'm looking for a solution that is faster than scraping every post on the blog and finding the image. There are hundreds of posts. The display I'll build from the JSON is the primary part of the home page, so it needs to load very fast (as in ~2 seconds or less).

Comment: Could you give me an example site you may want to use this on so I can try it myself?

Comment: Finally heard back from the client. Sorry, but the site is under development and he doesn't want to show anyone yet.